# Adding the standard check spelling button to a visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I'm overriding the std page layout for tasks in some instances with a VF page, and I want to give the users the same functionality as the "check spelling" standard button that occurs on the standard page layout. According to the documentation on Std controllers, it isn't availible. is that right?? I can't imagine having to re-create the wheel for a feature like this.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_controller_std_actions.htm

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to add that. However, I would suggest that as a workaround, pretty much ever modern web browser now either has a built-in spell checker or easy add-ons for spell checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to do this in Visualforce aside from including a link to a JavaScript [spell checker](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/13521/72). Otherwise, make sure you're using a modern browser like [Internet Explorer 10](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/ie-10-worldwide-languages), [Firefox](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/), or [Chrome](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/) as recommended in the comments; all of these have spell checking built in.

If however, you're attempting this from a standard page layout, you could try creating a new JavaScript Custom Button with this code:

```
doSpell({ctrl:'tsk6',lang:'en_US',title:'Check Spelling',intLang:'en_US'}, '/servlet/SProxyWrapper', document.location.protocol + '//' + 'spell-chi.salesforce.com/spellcheck', 'There is nothing to check', 'We are sorry,our spellchecker currently does not support the browser you are using. Please upgrade your browser.', 'The Spell Checker is not available in this language.');
```

Please note, this is a hack that uses functionality that Salesforce may discontinue or make unavailable in the future.