# Spellcheck within a custom object/textarea/Notes field

Tags: visualforce, javascript, custom-object, jquery

And now, some backstory.

I have no previous Salesforce experience, and I'm an emerging developer.  I work for a company that uses the Opportunities section to track clients and the insurance products they decide to purchase.  The notes section that is built into each Opportunity is a textArea that needs to be considered for spellchecking, but when I test this out in the sandbox, Chrome, Firefox, and IE8/10 do not show the spelling errors for this area.  I have built a separate testpage which would make a call to an outside server to check the spelling/grammar with AftertheDeadline, but the IT department is coming down on me for the lack of security in making this callout.

The question is, can anyone recommend either a plug in or code that would check the spelling of this textArea, or any text fields located on the page for that matter?

The reason why I mention a custom object in the title is that I believe the note information is captured in the object Note__c.

Thanks,
J

P.S. I would also like to add that in trying to implement the spellchecking on my own custom test page, I was able to receive indications of misspelled words when including the following code from AfterTheDeadline (in IE10, Firefox, and Chrome...not IE8:():

1. include jQuery ... naturally none of this works without jQuery

   script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.js"
2. load the atd.textarea.js -- this script makes it easy to attach AtD to a textarea

   src="scripts/jquery.atd.textarea.js"
3. this script is a hack that allows cross-domain AJAX

   src="scripts/csshttprequest.js"
4. this CSS file contains the style information for highlighted errors

   link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/atd.css"

Comment: Is it captured in the Standard Notes & Attachments related list of a custom object called Note__c?  If so then the standard spell checking will work: Under the Setup menu click the User Interface link and there is a setting *Enable Spell Checker*.  Also, for what it is worth, almost all modern web browsers have spell check built in to them.  You might want to suggest that.

Comment: Alas, it is not, as I have seen that box to enable Spell Checker (why, dear Salesforce, would you have that box when the answer is clearly 'yes'?) in other areas.  And yes, while I agree that modern web browswers have spell check, the less savvy members of my organization would be better assisted by avoiding stepping out of the textarea, especially in the field on mobile devices.  Thanks.

Comment: I know this is not the answer you probably need, but after over a decade of spell checker requests, I would strongly point you towards native browser-based solutions. The JS-based and otherwise community solutions are way more flawed, less supported, and less durable options. If you have a specific requirement like "I need Windows IE6 users to not be able to submit a textarea with spelling errors", open a new question about that or clarify your original question.

Comment: @jkraybill Please, if you know how to get the browser to recognize the custom textArea object, let me know.  I totally agree with you that this would be the right solution, but it's not inherently obvious to me as to implementation.

Comment: did any one tested spell checker with  Bjspell.js ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think in closing this question, my continued research led me to this post in the Answers section of the success portion of Salesforce: [Custom object spell check post.](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000h0kPAAQ)  The post goes on to include [this link](http://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrqxAAC) in order to vote the issue up so it is included in a future release.  If you have looked for this answer and Salesforce has not yet updated this possible feature, please select the link and vote the issue up.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, it would be best to use [Static Resources](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_resources.htm) with a pure client-side JavaScript spell check plugin. Using scripts included in Static Resources only, you shouldn't have any cross-domain issues.

You may want to try:

- [bjspell](https://code.google.com/p/bjspell/)

Please note, I haven't tested it, though.

Comment: This is a possibility, although in looking at the site and corresponding blog, it looks like it may only be in beta.  I'll see if I can include it today. +1

Comment: @Matthew Keefe I have included Bjspell.js file in static resource and included the script using apex:includescript in my visualforce page but still spell checker is not working